# Qt program run errors

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 Qt programs that are basically identical, I copied the code from one of them to the other to modify it and save it as a new project, now the second one doesn't run and gives a bunch of errors which don't make sense because the other one runs and they are the same where the errors are coming up. Here is the code:

```
#ifndef FILM_H
#define FILM_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <QDate>

class Film: public QObject{
Q_OBJECT

Q_PROPERTY( QString title READ getTitle WRITE setTitle);
Q_PROPERTY( int duration READ getDuration WRITE setDuration);
Q_PROPERTY( QString director READ getDirector WRITE setDirector);
Q_PROPERTY( QDate releaseDate READ getReleaseDate WRITE setReleaseDate);

public:
    Film(QString t,int dur,QString dir,QDate r);
    Film();
    void setTitle(QString t);
    void setDuration(int dur);
    void setDirector(QString dir);
    void setReleaseDate(QDate r);
    QString getTitle() const;
    int getDuration() const;
    QString getDirector() const;
    QDate getReleaseDate() const;
    QString toString();

private:
    QString m_title;
    int m_duration;
    QString m_director;
    QDate m_releaseDate;

};

#endif // FILM_H


#ifndef FILMWRITER_H
#define FILMWRITER_H
#include "Film.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QFile>

class FilmWriter{

public:
    void accessFilm(Film& f);

};
#endif // FILMWRITER_H


#ifndef FILMINPUT_H
#define FILMINPUT_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "Film.h"
#include "FilmWriter.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui {
    class FilmInput;
}

class FilmInput : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FilmInput(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FilmInput();
    void obtainFilmData(Film& f);
    void saveFilm(Film& f);
public slots:
    void getFilm();
private:
    Ui::FilmInput *ui;
    //widgets
    QMainWindow* window;
    QLabel* infoLabel;
    QLabel* titleLabel;
    QLabel* durationLabel;
    QLabel* directorLabel;
    QLabel* relDateLabel;
    QTextEdit* titleEdit;
    QTextEdit* durationEdit;
    QTextEdit* directorEdit;
    QTextEdit* relDateEdit;
    QPushButton* saveBtn;
    QPushButton* cancelBtn;
    Film f;
    //sets up gui and connects signals and slots
    void setUpGui();
};

#endif // FILMINPUT_H


#include "Film.h"
#include <QDate>
#include <QString>

Film::Film(QString t,int dur,QString dir,QDate r):m_title(t),m_duration(dur),m_director(dir),m_releaseDate(r){

}

Film::Film(){
}

void Film::setTitle(QString t){
    m_title = t;
}

void Film::setDuration(int dur){
    m_duration = dur;
}

void Film::setDirector(QString dir){
    m_director = dir;
}

void Film::setReleaseDate(QDate r){
    m_releaseDate = r;
}

QString Film::getTitle() const{
    return QString("%1").arg(m_title);
}

int Film::getDuration() const{
    return m_duration;
}
QString Film::getDirector() const{
    return QString("%1").arg(m_director);
}
QDate Film::getReleaseDate() const{
    return m_releaseDate;
}
QString Film::toString()
{
  return m_title + " " + m_duration + " " + m_director + " " + m_releaseDate.toString();
}



#include "FilmWriter.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTextStream>

void FilmWriter::accessFilm(Film& f){
    QVariant v1 = f.property("title");
    QVariant v2 = f.property("duration");
    QVariant v3 = f.property("director");
    QVariant v4 = f.property("releaseDate");
    QString str = v1.toString() +" "+ v2.toString() +" "+ v3.toString() +" "+ v4.toString();
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(str);
    msgBox.exec();
}



#include "filminput.h"
#include "ui_filminput.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include "Film.h"
#include "FilmWriter.h"
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QDate>
#include <QString>

FilmInput::FilmInput(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::FilmInput)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setUpGui();
}

FilmInput::~FilmInput()
{
    delete ui;
}

void FilmInput::setUpGui(){
    //initialise widgets
    infoLabel = new QLabel("Please enter film data which will be saved to a file",this);
    titleLabel = new QLabel("Film Title",this);
    durationLabel = new QLabel("Film Duration",this);
    directorLabel = new QLabel("Film Director",this);
    relDateLabel = new QLabel("Film Release Date",this);
    titleEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    durationEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    directorEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    relDateEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    saveBtn = new QPushButton("Save Film",this);
    cancelBtn = new QPushButton("Cancel",this);
    //set layout
    QFormLayout* layout = new QFormLayout();
    layout->addWidget(infoLabel);
    layout->addWidget(titleLabel);
    layout->addWidget(titleEdit);
    layout->addWidget(durationLabel);
    layout->addWidget(durationEdit);
    layout->addWidget(directorLabel);
    layout->addWidget(directorEdit);
    layout->addWidget(relDateLabel);
    layout->addWidget(relDateEdit);
    layout->addWidget(saveBtn);
    layout->addWidget(cancelBtn);

    this->ui->widget->setLayout(layout);
    this->setWindowTitle("Film Archive");
    connect(saveBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(getFilm()));
    connect(cancelBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
}

void FilmInput::getFilm(){
    Film f1(titleEdit->toPlainText(),durationEdit->toPlainText().toInt() ,directorEdit->toPlainText(),
             QDate::fromString(relDateEdit->toPlainText(),"dd/MM/YYYY"));;
    obtainFilmData(f1);
}

void FilmInput::obtainFilmData(Film &f){
    FilmWriter f2;
    f2.accessFilm(f);
}




#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "filminput.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    FilmInput w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

the error dump:

```
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp: In constructor 'FilmInput::FilmInput(QWidget*)': 
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::FilmInput' 
..\Ass1Q2\/filminput.h:12: error: forward declaration of 'struct Ui::FilmInput' 
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::FilmInput' 
..\Ass1Q2\/filminput.h:12: error: forward declaration of 'struct Ui::FilmInput' 
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp: In destructor 'virtual FilmInput::~FilmInput()': 
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp:20: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: 
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp:20: warning: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::FilmInput' 
..\Ass1Q2\/filminput.h:12: warning: forward declaration of 'struct Ui::FilmInput' 
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp:20: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined. 
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp: In member function 'void FilmInput::setUpGui()': 
..\Ass1Q2\filminput.cpp:50: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::FilmInput' 
..\Ass1Q2\/filminput.h:12: error: forward declaration of 'struct Ui::FilmInput' 
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Unisa/COS3711/assignments/Ass1Q2-build-desktop' 
mingw32-make: Leaving directory `C:/Unisa/COS3711/assignments/Ass1Q2-build-desktop' 
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/filminput.o] Error 1 
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2 
The process "C:/Qt/2010.04/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" exited with code %2.
Error while building project Ass1Q2 (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Comment: what's in your pro file?  sounds like you're either missing files or missing paths that should point to whatever is defining Ui::FilmInput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copied the code, but not pro file. So, you may miss to add UI file to profile, to invoc UI compiler to generate "ui_FileInput.h" source. Please copy UI file and update .pro file with FORMS    += FileInput.ui may solve your problem. To know better you can comment "ui_FileInput.h"  and see the behaviour.

Comment: here is the .pro file, already has FORMS+=FileInput.ui and still doesn't work
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-08-14T23:02:10
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

TARGET = Ass1Q2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        filminput.cpp \
    Film.cpp \
    FilmWriter.cpp

HEADERS  += filminput.h \
    Film.h \
    FilmWriter.h

FORMS    += fileinput.ui

Comment: Please update UI file object name as "FilmInput", then save and build again.

Comment: #-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-08-14T23:02:10
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

TARGET = Ass1Q2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        filminput.cpp \
    Film.cpp \
    FilmWriter.cpp

HEADERS  += filminput.h \
    Film.h \
    FilmWriter.h

FORMS    += FilmInput.ui


       

.pro file updated and rebuild and still giving the same errors as originally posted.

Comment: @user2291259  update UI file, not PRO. your PRO file is OK. Please open User interface(*.UI) file in designer, then rename root object name to "FilmInput".